# how to let others access my home directory

Tags: linux

I grant read privilege to all the users to my .vimrc file . But my colleague still can't read my .vimrc file . I guess in addiction to give the read privilege to the .vimrc file, in some way I should give the person who want to read it the "access right" to my home directory first---which I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you need the "x" privilege on your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

First, choose a directory that anyone can access (for example `/home/public` )

Second, create a symbolic link of this file into this directory

```
$ln -sv ~/.vimrc /home/public/
```

Answer (score 1):

if your colleagues are members of your group you could grant access to your home directory by `chmod g+x /home/yourname`, and then `chmod g+r /home/yourname/.vimrc`

Regards